# Why is same SQL query invalid in c++ program but prints results in BD Browser

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a c++ program that uses SQLite version 3.43.1. (DB Browser version 3.12.2 which has SQLite version 3.35.5). I create a table and insert data in that table. When I want to read the table: `SELECT NAME FROM "mytable"`, I get an error code 1 and error message `no such table: mytable`.

NOTE: I see a lot of previous answers saying "you need to point to the db". I am querying from the same db I had written to without error. I also use DB browser (once my program is disconnected), and I use the same exact query and see my data.

I also used the following query within my program to see a list of tables: `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE 'mytable'`.

How is this even possible? I have no idea how to proceed.

Also note: I attempted both sqlite_exec and the non-wrapped approach (prepare_v2, step, sqlite3_column_text). At this point, I don't see how changing between using callback or step+column_text does anything different.

The creation of db is done using regular sqlite3_open. No arguments other than the filepath. Creation of table uses default `CREATE TABLE mytable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, VAL TEXT);`. Nothing else.

I am compiling using g++ 12.3.0 on a Ubuntu 12.3.0 (through windows WSL) on the sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c files provided by zipped sqlite-amalgamation-343100 from the sqlite website.

Equivalent compile command: `gcc -fPIC -lpthread -ldl -lm -c sqlite3.o -o code/sqlite-amalgamation-3430100/sqlite3.c`

db.h

```
#pragma once

// Third-Party
#include <sqlite3.h>

// C++ Standard
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

class DB {
 public:
  void setFilepath(std::filesystem::path);
  std::filesystem::path getFilepath();
  void connect();
  void close();
  void write(std::string);
  void read(std::string);
 private:
  sqlite3* db;
  std::filesystem::path db_path;
}
```

db.cpp

```
#include "db.h"

static int callback(void* list, int cols, char** dat, char** colname) {
  std::cout << "callback called" << std::endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    printf("%s = %s\n", colname[i], dat[i] ? dat[i] : "NULL");
    std::cout << colname[i] << " = " << dat[i] << std::endl;
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}

void DB::setFilepath(std::filesystem::path fp) {
  std::string msg = "DB set filepath " + fp.string();
  spdlog::info(msg);

  if (fp.extension() != ".db") {
    fp.replace_extension(".db");
  }

  db_path = fp;

  return;
}

std::filesystem::path DB::getFilepath() {
  return db_path;
}

void DB::connect() {
  int ret_code = sqlite3_open(db_path.string().c_str(), &db);
  //const char* zVfs = "";
  //int ret_code = sqlite3_open_v2(db_path.string().c_str(), &db, 0, zVfs);
  if (ret_code) {
    std::string msg1 = "DB return code error ";
    std::string msg2 = sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    spdlog::error(msg1 + msg2);
    exit(0);
  }
}

void DB::close() {
  sqlite3_close(db);
}

void DB::write(std::string query) {
  connect();
  int ret_code;
  char* pzErrMsg = 0;
  ret_code = sqlite3_exec(db, sql_str.c_str(), callback, pArg, &pzErrMsg);

  if (ret_code != SQLITE_OK) {
    spdlog::error("Execution error");
    sqlite3_free(pzErrMsg);
  }
  close();

  return;
}

void DB::read(std::string sql_str) {
  int ret_code = 0;
  sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
  char* zErrMsg = 0;

  connect();
  ret_code = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql_str.c_str(), -1, &stmt, nullptr);
  std::cout << "ret code: " << ret_code << std::endl;

  // I receive the error HERE
  // #########################################################
  // exe fail
  // no such table: mytable <--------------- HERE
  // #########################################################
  if (ret_code != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cout << "exec fail" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    exit(1);
  }


  do {
    ret_code = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    // #########################################################
    // # PLEASE DO NOT WORRY ABOUT THIS RIGHT NOW              #
    // # THIS IS NOT WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS                    #
    // #########################################################
    std::cout << "ret code loop: " << ret_code << std::endl;
    std::cout << sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0) << ":";
    std::cout << sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1) << std::endl;
  } while (ret_code == SQLITE_ROW);

  if (ret_code != SQLITE_DONE) { // 101
    std::cout << "ret_code not done" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
  }
  
  // close
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

main.cpp

```
// C Standard
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Custom - Utils
#include "db.h"

// C++ Standard
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void createTables(DB proj_db) {
  proj_db.write("CREATE TABLE mytable (\"ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, VALUE TEXT\");");
  proj_db.write("CREATE TABLE myOtherTable (\"ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, VALUE TEXT\");");
}

void writeDatafromFile(json file, DB proj_db) {
  // read data
  ...

  // write to DB
  proj_db.write("INSERT INTO mytable (NAME,VALUE) \"abc\",\"123\"");
}

void readDatabase(DB proj_db) {
  proj_db.read("SELECT NAME FROM \"mytable\";"); //fail
  proj_db.read("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE \'mytable\';"); // output is empty; doesn't see any tables to list; should at least list my table creations

  // write to csv
  ...
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  DB proj_db;
  proj_db = DB();
  std::filesystem::path db_fp; // obtained from arguments, same directory is fine. ends with .db. example: ./mydatabase.db
  proj_db.setFilepath(db_fp);
  
  if (arguments.new()) createTables();
  if (arguments.inputFileExists()) writeDatafromFile();
  if (arguments.outputFlagExists()) readDatabase();

  return 0;
}
```

bash terminal:

```
rm -rf myproject.db # this is to ensure a new sqlite db is created
./myprogram --db myproject --new     # I create a blank sql db file called myproject.db; creates empty tables (mytable, myOthertable, etc)
./myprogram --db myproject --in data.json # I write data parsed from a file (equivalent to ~2-3 INSERT mytable sql commands); successful; verified with DB browser after program is closed
./myprogram --db myproject --in data2.json # another set of writes (sometimes to another table); successful; verified with DB Browser
./myprogram --db myproject --out mystuff.csv # queries tables (SELECT NAME from mytable) <------ ERROR HERE, but DB Browser shows data and my schema
```

My actual program returns values for the read command. Just didn't want to complicate this minimal program. As long as I can get the error code fixed, I can handle the rest.

Comment: also, I understand I didn't include details of the code, but can I at least include it before closing the question?

Comment: `sqlite3* db;` probably should not be a class member variable if every operation you do opens and closes the database.

Comment: What sqlite error message was printed when ` proj_db.read("SELECT NAME FROM \"mytable\";");` failed?

Comment: how can I recreate a db handler? I absolutely need to close my program after every run. (my understanding was that the filepath connection would return an equivalent db handler since it is the same exact filepath. I see my data in DB browser of two separate writes)

Comment: no such table: mytable

Comment: You can just make it a local variable and adjust your function signature for connect to `void connect(sqlite3 & db)`

Comment: Does `proj_db.read("SELECT NAME FROM mytable;");` give you the same error?

Comment: that is fine. but I am still closing my program after every write. then restarting my program to read, thus removing it from class member still acts the same way.

Comment: yes. there is no such table

Comment: `...\"mytable\"...` looks suspicious, remove the double-quotes and try again

Comment: Tried it already. Tried 'mytable' , "mytable" , main.mytable , main."mytable" , and numerous variations I've seen on stackoverflow and DB browser.

Comment: I don't see the problem however my usage of sqlite in c++ has been mainly with the Qt classes so I will have to leave it to someone else to help.

Comment: sqlite uses several different quoting methods [https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) however for an identifier if the name is just letters and no spaces or other characters you should not need to quote. These days if I quote I have moved to prefer using [] since you don't need to escape or use raw string literals in c++ for that.

Comment: " but can I at least include it before closing the question?" you have all the time you need to post a question. When the question is edited after it was closed it goes into a review queue, will be reviewed, and reopened when user vote for it.

Comment: `proj_db.write("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, VALUE TEXT);");`
`proj_db.write("INSERT INTO mytable (NAME,VALUE) VALUES ('abc','123')");`
`proj_db.read("SELECT NAME, VALUE FROM mytable;");`
`proj_db.read("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE \'mytable\';");`
works for me, so your insert as well as your select statement was wrong

Comment: ... and in the DB::read method you need `if (ret_code == SQLITE_ROW) {...}` inside the DO-loop

Comment: i think this is the issue with the code snippet. I close my program after a write. then I start the program with a different set of arguments (a different write that adds data), then a different run of the program that does the read. So the c++ program can't read, but it was able to perform all the same writes according to DB Browser.

Comment: I can error check in the do-while loop. However, that is not my concern at the moment. The first instance of error checking is what fails. (right after the sqlite3_prepare_v2).

Answer (score 0):

```
proj_db.write("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, VALUE TEXT);"); 
proj_db.write("INSERT INTO mytable (NAME,VALUE) VALUES ('abc','123')"); 
proj_db.read("SELECT NAME, VALUE FROM mytable;");
proj_db.read("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE \'mytable\';");
```

works for me, so your insert as well as your select statement were wrong. Especially your DB::read method tries to read two column values so you need a `select` which returns at least two text values. Additionally you need

```
if (ret_code == SQLITE_ROW) {...}
```

in the DO-loop

(and delete your existing DB once before testing)

Comment: I do now see the attempted read of 2 values per row. I would have expected a different error than `no such table: mytable` I am a little confused at that. Was this the error you had when you tested? Edit: Oh, It says in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob) that the result is undefined when an invalid column index: ***If the SQL statement does not currently point to a valid row, or if the column index is out of range, the result is undefined.***

Comment: `std::cout << sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0) << ":";` and 
`std::cout << sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1) << std::endl;` read two columns...

Comment: this is just a code snippet. The actual code closes the program once a single or set of operation occurs. Then another instance of the program runs, it opens the DB again, and does a read or write. I would have to include the entire program to showcase this which may expand on the issue.

Comment: I am not concerned with the column_text at the moment. The error occurs during prepare_v2.

Comment: then try SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE (only) as the 3rd argument to sqlite3_open_v2() and just run the read part of your program

Comment: What is the difference between just sqlite3_open? According to documentation, 3rd argument is already SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE or SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE (with 4th arg being NULL )

Comment: The point is that the original code snippet in your question together with the changes in my answer work. If I comment the "create" and "insert" part it still works, so for sure I can read the existing(!) DB just with the read part. If this is not possible in your setup my suspicion is that you may create somehow each time a new DB in your test of "read". If you change the "open" behavior you will see if you really open an existing DB, double-check the exact path of the DB (maybe debug/release folder?) etc.

Comment: I know it is indeed not another new DB because 1) I use the same filepath and 2) I have checked using DB Browser. I see that many, many answers in previous stack overflow questions default to this ("check your filepath"). However, I have done this. That is the reason for the new question created here. (also, I do delete my db file after testing each run. I have a makefile that does this, I should update that bash script to show that)

Comment: ***I do delete my db file after testing each run. I have a makefile that does this*** Maybe this is the cause of your problems. Some weird timing bug causing the database to be deleted while you are testing.

Comment: No. I am saying that I am running a clean test every time. I first have a directory without any db file. Then I run the makefile which creates a new project (new db), then writes either a set of writes or an individual write (using my program based on arguments in terminal). Then I attempt to read. Afterwards, once everything is done and my program is closed, I will inspect my db file with DB Browser. Nothing multithreaded or anything is going on.

Comment: omg.... hey thanks for the help everyone. found out what it was.... argument parser setup of db only sets up during creation / writes. never "setup" during the third part of my project (the read part). should have blocked (`exit(1)`) attempt to read DB without proper setup. going to go hide in a cave now. sincerely, thank you.